# can we solve this problem using conditional statements

Tags: python-3.x

A number x is nice if it is of the form 3y+1, is calm if it is of the form 3y+2 and is cool if it is of form 3y.
Given a number x, print if it is nice, cool or calm.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `%` operator, you can separate numbers of the form `3y + 1` from the ones of the form `3y + 2` from the ones of the form `3y`. The `%` operator is the "modulus" operator.

Then use an `if - elif - else` structure or, if you are not familiar with `elif`, two `if - else` statements, one inside the other!